# Check if string contains a character in a set?

Tags: scala

I can do this:

```
val result = input.contains('a') || input.contains('b') || input.contains('c')
```

but what's a more idiomatic way of doing the above? I ideally would just have something like:

```
val identifiers = Set('a', 'b', 'c')
val result = // check if "input" contains one of the characters in "identifiers"
```

Comment: You have the method `exists`

Comment: Expanding what Gastón said: `str.exists(charsSet.contains)`

Comment: `input.exists(identifiers)` is enough.